# Add FFTW library to QT project

Tags: c++, qt, dll, fftw

I'm trying to add FFTW library to my QT project. I downloaded fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip from [page](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html).

After that I unzipped it, and copy all file to "c:\fftw" directory.
In my project setting I added line like below

```
INCLUDEPATH += "c:\fftw"
LIBS += -L "c:\fftw" -lfftw3-3
```

And then, in my MainWindow.h I included it like below

```
#include <fftw/fftw3.h>
```

Unfortunately, I can't rebuild my project. I have the following error:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fftw/fftw3.h': No such file or directory
```

Do you have any ideas what should I do? List of files in "c:\fftw" directory.

```
 Directory of c:\fftw

2016-11-20  14:15    <DIR>          .
2016-11-20  14:15    <DIR>          ..
2016-07-30  22:38           400˙306 bench.exe
2016-07-30  22:42           411˙177 benchf.exe
2016-07-30  22:44           380˙107 benchl.exe
2016-07-30  20:21            18˙342 COPYING
2016-07-30  20:21               863 COPYRIGHT
2016-07-30  22:38           184˙625 fftw-wisdom.exe
2016-07-30  22:44             2˙519 fftw3.f
2016-07-30  22:44            55˙850 fftw3.f03
2016-07-30  22:44            18˙517 fftw3.h
2016-07-30  22:44            27˙592 fftw3l.f03
2016-07-30  22:44            26˙291 fftw3q.f03
2016-07-30  22:42           184˙732 fftwf-wisdom.exe
2016-07-30  22:44           184˙732 fftwl-wisdom.exe
2016-07-30  22:44            24˙067 libfftw3-3.def
2016-07-30  22:38         2˙712˙765 libfftw3-3.dll
2016-07-30  22:44            24˙985 libfftw3f-3.def
2016-07-30  22:42         2˙772˙692 libfftw3f-3.dll
2016-07-30  22:44            14˙465 libfftw3l-3.def
2016-07-30  22:44         1˙247˙967 libfftw3l-3.dll
2016-11-20  14:15                 0 lista.txt
2016-07-30  20:21            22˙670 NEWS
2016-07-30  20:21             1˙827 README
2016-07-30  22:44             2˙079 README-bench
2016-07-30  22:44             1˙293 README-WINDOWS
              24 File(s)      8˙720˙463 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  17˙799˙467˙008 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it. It seems that it was my mistake.

Problem:

I was using MSVC2013 64bit compiler. On [FFTW page](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html) there is information that I need run lib.exe for VS with three def files in directory. I was trying to do that, but I wasn't able to do it. I had some lib.exe problems.

```
lib /def:libfftw3-3.def
lib /def:libfftw3f-3.def
lib /def:libfftw3l-3.def
```

Solution:

I've changed in Qt building to MinGW 32bit and I downloaded 32bit version of fftw. Now it's working perfectly

Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that the include should be corrected.
Since you already set your INCLUDEPATH to **c:\fftw** you should probably use

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

without specifying the subdirectory.
Unless you want to do it the other way around.

**EDIT:**
According to an example in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html) you might also try updating the backslash to slash in your path. However, as far as I checked in my environment it works in both cases.

**EDIT:**
Adding a sample code with Qt and FFTW on authors request - issue not reproduced

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    fftw_complex in[5];

    return a.exec();
}
```

Project file:

```
QT += core gui
CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = FFTW_test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += c:/Tools/fftw
LIBS += -Lc:/Tools/fftw -lfftw3-3

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Verified on Win8.1 with Qt5.3 and FFTW from authors question.

Comment: It's not solution. I checked it before too.

Comment: In this case I must say I cannot reproduce your problem. I already downloaded the fftw added to an empty project according to your description and it works fine for me.

Comment: Can you add your .pro file? I did empty project right now and it's still not working. What is your system? Which qt version?

Comment: Added the code used for reproduction. Maybe it helps.